# Huge latency to connect webapp to docker mysql container via Hibernate

Tags: mysql, tomcat, docker, web-applications

I'm trying to port my web-app created on Windows, using Hibernate, XAMPP for Apache tomcat and mysql server, to Linux, using Docker.

After i've done the following steps, The first feature of my web.app is login/register form: On Windows all works perfectly, but with container there is latency about tens of minutes.. and sometime there is also 500 http error!!

1. `docker run -d --name mysql-phpmyadmin -p 127.0.0.1:8686:80 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 grzesiekb/mysql-phpmyadmin`
2. `docker run -d -p 8484:8080 -p 8007:8009 --name tomcat8-linked --link mysql-phpmyadmin:mysqlphp tomcat:8.0-jre8`  and then deploy under webapps/ folder my warfile
3. In my hibernate.cfg.xml, you can see it [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31285) (i have problems to paste it in a viewable way) :)
4. in my mysql container my.cnf there is:

> [client]
>       port            = 3306
>       socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> ```
> # Here is entries for some specific programs
> # The following values assume you have at least 32M ram
>
> # This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
> [mysqld_safe]
> socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> nice            = 0
>
> [mysqld]
> #
> # * Basic Settings
> #
> user            = mysql
> pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
> socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> port            = 3306
> basedir         = /usr
> datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
> tmpdir          = /tmp
> lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
> skip-external-locking
> #
> # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
> # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
> bind-address = 0.0.0.0
> #
> # * Fine Tuning
> #
> key_buffer              = 16M
> max_allowed_packet      = 16M
> thread_stack            = 192K
> thread_cache_size       = 8
> # This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
> # the first time they are touched
> myisam-recover         = BACKUP
> #max_connections        = 100
> #table_cache            = 64
> #thread_concurrency     = 10
> #
> # * Query Cache Configuration
> #
> query_cache_limit       = 1M
> query_cache_size        = 16M
> #
> # * Logging and Replication
> #
> # Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
> # Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
> # As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
> general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
> general_log             = 1
> #
> # Error log - should be very few entries.
> #
> log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
> #
> # Here you can see queries with especially long duration
> #slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
> #slow_query_log      = 1
> #long_query_time = 2
> #log_queries_not_using_indexes
> #
> # The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
> # note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
> #       other settings you may need to change.
> #server-id              = 1
> #log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
> expire_logs_days        = 10
> max_binlog_size         = 100M
> #binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
> #binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
>
> # * InnoDB
> #
> # InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
> # Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
> #
> # * Security Features
> #
> # Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
> # chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
> #
> # For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
> #
> # ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
> # ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
> # ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
>
>
> [mysqldump]
> quick
> quote-names
> max_allowed_packet      = 16M
>
> [mysql]
> #no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
>
> [isamchk]
> key_buffer              = 16M
>
> #
> # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
> #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
> #
> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
> ```

5. By default, this mysql container only allows connection from localhost: for allowing connections from everywhere, i've done:

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Then i've imported my dql dump via phpmyadmin

**Describe the results you received:**

Huge latency, related to i don't know which problem, and in a random way there is no way to connect to mysql. No logs. My teacher said that probably it's a DNS problem related to Docker network.

**Describe the results you expected:**

Connection to the db immediately, like in Windows using XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make your setup as standard as possible to avoid bugs due to non-standard practices.

- Use official or at least popular images (with millions of pulls) instead of your mysql-phpmyadmin with a hundred pulls :

  - https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=1&page=1&pullCount=0&q=mysql
  - https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=phpmyadmin
- I'm not sure why you declare ip with host port and container port, maybe don't do this if it's not necessary, publish only host port and container port, not ip.
- Don't use --link since it's [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/), create a bridge network and run each container with --network my-bridge-network.
- Upgrade your Ubuntu to the latest LTS version (16.04.2) with the latest available "HWE" kernel for this LTS version (you have to upgrade kernel with a seperate command as explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) : `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tristan. I've tried with this new mysql container:
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -p 3307:3306 -d mysql

then this one for phpmyadmin:
docker run': docker run --name myadmin -d --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8686:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

I've given value "0.0.0.0" to bind_address in mysql config file;
then i created a bridge docker network, i've attached tomcat and mysql containers; then, in the hibernate.cfg.xml file, i've pointed to <mysql_container_ip>:3306/at_db with user "root" and password "pass". But the problem remains!

Comment: Well, I've given you 4 advices, you've followed the first 2, you've ignored the last 2. You're getting close, just don't ignore any. And don't configure mysql config, this image is supposed to be preconfigured.

Comment: If it's not clear : don't forget to update your OS and kernel, and don't use "--link" for phpmyadmin, if you have a "latency" between tomcat and mysql, you should see the same between phpmyadmin and mysql.